# MongoDB getmore on a collection is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to debug a high CPU issue on MongoDB instance. We have two shard r3.large AWS instances. There are not many page faults compared to ops count.

System profile shows ton of getmore entries like below. Please help me in finding out what causing the getmore to be very slow.

```
    {
        "op" : "getmore",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "cursorid" : 74493486271,
        "ntoreturn" : 0,
        "keyUpdates" : 0,
        "numYield" : 7,
        "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(16140),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(6458801),
                "w" : NumberLong(294321)
            }
        },
        "nreturned" : 120,
        "responseLength" : 13100,
        "millis" : 6304,
        "execStats" : {

        },
        "ts" : ISODate("2015-06-16T14:20:39.886Z"),
        "client" : "1.5.1.3",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
    }
```

Comment: How does your replication lag look like?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg -  Thanks for responding.  The getmore is related to slow aggregate query.  Answered my own question as below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question it may help some one else.

- Enabled more logging with when CPU is high `db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, logLevel: 1 } )` , after did reset to logLevel: 0 (default).
- Then log showed up a aggregate query with 0ms, but right after that, getmore entry with 5 to 6 secs.
- Aggregate query has `cursor: { batchSize: 0 }` with initial batch size as zero.  So, the query returns quickly.  But when application started iterating thru cursor, then the getmore is logged and that entry doesn't have any query details.

  Fixing aggregating query $match to use indexes solved problem

Comment: Could you provide sample data and the aggregations?

Comment: @Samba, how did you specifically force the query to use the index?

Comment: @tomascharad, we had to change the order of elements in composite query.